# Can't import JS script from "static" in Flask environment

Tags: javascript, python, html, dom, flask

I am trying to import `mainfirst.js` onto an `HTML` page. I have tried both doing the following:

`<script src="../../../static/assets/js/main.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='assets/js/mainfirst.js') }}"></script>`

I am getting

Cannot resolve file `mainfirst.js` but it actually exists as per image:

[image]

Comment: do you mind providing your actual call stack for the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Where's your static folder placed comparing to your flask instance .py file? Flask isn't finding your static folder. Unless you modified on your blueprint, flask will look for the static folder on the same level of your main app.

So let's say you have your .py file that runs you app - flask_server.py on the example below - inside the first level of the "web" directory, flask will look for the static folder on the same level - the same is true for the templates folder:

[image]

Also `url_for` function would be a better way to call your static files, in your case it could be something like the following - assuming static folder is on the same level of the .py app running file:

```
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='assets/js/main.js')}}"></script>
```

Hope it suits you well. :)